# CSS dashed border always appears white in IE8, why?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, border

Here is the deal, I have following div with dashed borders:

```
.dashed-header {
    /*background-color: transparent;*/
    height: 87px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border-top: 1px dashed #613e27;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #613e27;
}
```

for some reason border is white instead of `#613e27` and I have no idea why it is so?
Here is my [webpage](http://freshbeer.lv/final/index.html) You can see this border in **dark brown header line.**

Comment: I believe it is a rendering error with IE8, since when I open the developer console it flashes between white and the true color. Probably caused by the transparent background.

Comment: Thez is probably right. The border switches between white and brown as I resize the window, try removing the `background-color: transparent`

Comment: removed transparent background, still white ;/

Comment: border-color: #613e27 !important; work? (I can't test in IE sorry)

Comment: do you have stand-alone IE8 or do you emulate ie8 in ie9?

Comment: @tsdexter Thnx man, it worked, want to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
border-color: #613e27 !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have IE8 and it work fine, I put it inside another div to see if the color disappear or not, but the color still exist

```
<style>
.main {
    height: 200px;
    width:200px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color:#A1Ae27;
    padding: 15px;
}
.dashed-header {
    /*background-color: transparent;*/
    height: 87px;
    width:100px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border-top: 1px dashed #613e27;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #613e27;
}
</style>
<body>

<div class="main">
    <div class="dashed-header">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

try to change to solid border and see does they appear whit too in your EI8?