# IE8 problems using Class and CSS to set border colour?

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have an `image` in a `div` , and the `div` has a border color set using a class identifier in the associated `CSS` file.

There is a similar thread here [CSS dashed border always appears white in IE8, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992718/css-dashed-border-always-appears-white-in-ie8-why) and not helped me. That's why I created a new thread.

The code for the div and image looks like this:

```
      <div class="toolbarIcon" id="agent_login" ><img width="40px" height="40px" src="toolbar/user_login.png"/><pre class="toolbarLabel">Login</pre></div>
```

In the associated CSS file the code looks like this:

```
.toolbarIcon {
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: red;

    width: 60px;
    height: 55px;
    float: left;
}
```

In addition to that I used `jquery.corner.js` to round the `div` corner.I thing this is the reason for the problem.

My Jquery will be,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("#toolbar").corner("5px");
     $(".toolbarIcon").corner("5px");   
});
```

`IE8` does not display the border (color red) correctly.

All other leading browsers (Firefox, Opera, Safari and Chrome) paint the border the required red.

I presume that I am doing something that `IE8` does not support but this is so simplistic I don't see what. Can anyone help me put this right.

Hope our stack user will help me.

Good answers are definitely appreciated.

Comment: This is a little Fiddle with your info: http://jsfiddle.net/xndY3/ does it work correctly to you? If yes, then maybe the problem is somewhere else (have you checked your `DOCTYPE` at the beginning of your html file?). I can't check IE8, since i'm on linux :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by replacing the jquery code from,

```
$(".toolbarIcon").corner("5px");
```

to,

```
$(".toolbarIcon").corner("keep 5px");
```

Thanks for all who supported me.